# JacORB 3.2 NameService (ns) seems not to read "orb.properties" file

Tags: java, corba, jacorb, nameservice

I've got a problem with JacORB 3.2 as it seems that it doesn't read the `orb.properties` file, and especially the `ORBInitRef.NameService` property.

As stated in the documentation on chapter 3.1, JacORB automatically searches for the orb.properties file in three locations: the `"java.home"/lib` directory, the `"user.home"` directory and inside the classpath.

This is the evidence that I'm not totally drunk:

Java command:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre
/home/emanuele
```

Bash command:

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib | grep orb.properties ; ls /home/emanuele | grep orb.properties
```

Output:

```
jacorb.properties
orb.properties
jacorb.properties
orb.properties
```

These four `.properties` file are exactly the same. Please have a look at the URI of the file that contains the reference (IOR) of the NameService:

```
ORBInitRef.NameService=file:/tmp/CORBA/NS_Ref
```

The problem is that, when I try to launch the NameService without any parameter (ns) I got these error messages:

```
giu 05, 2013 9:56:51 PM org.jacorb.naming.NameServer main
SEVERE: unexpected exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:/NS_Ref (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at org.jacorb.naming.NameServer.main(NameServer.java:320)

java.lang.RuntimeException: c:/NS_Ref (No such file or directory)
    at org.jacorb.naming.NameServer.main(NameServer.java:335)
```

Of course, if I explicitely pass the URI through console, everything goes fine

```
ns -Djacorb.naming.ior_filename=/tmp/CORBA/NS_Ref
```

The very strange thing is that, after the NameService is running, *EVERY OTHER OBJECT* can correctly and automatically resolve the initial reference of the NameService.

```
NamingContextExt nc = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService"));
```

The previous Java code returns a valid object. That does not make any sense for me.
And why does the NameService try to write its IOR inside a random file like C:\NS_Ref while I'm on Linux?

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you mixed up some different things in your question.

1. The location of the NS's IOR
2. The ability to read and use this IOR by other programs

**First.** Starting the NamingService is **not** affected by option `ORBInitRef.NameService` or any related commandline option. If you want the NamingService to drop it's IOR in a file, use

```
# The file where the name server drops its IOR
jacorb.naming.ior_filename=file:///tmp/CORBA/NS_Ref
```

as you already did. If this behaves different when using this as cmdline option, see 2.

**Second.** JacORB its config files are not OS specific - there is a mix of both Linux and Windows style. Don't rely on that.

Your call to `ns` will call the `jaco` script in JacORBs `bin` directory. Activate the verbosity stuff at the end of the file, then start `ns` again and see which `jre` and `jacorb.home` are really used. Look for configs. Remove ALL other configs you do not need.

Retry.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
ns -Djacorb.naming.ior_filename=/tmp/CORBA/NS_Ref
```

looks fine, but shouldn't that

```
ORBInitRef.NameService=file:/tmp/CORBA/NS_Ref
```

read `file:///tmp/CORBA/NS_Ref`?

And this

```
c:/NS_Ref
```

is strange on Linux; that looks very windowzy to me; are you sure you've not mixed Win and Linux config files?